# How to add a Done(Check) button on top right in a Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I've been struggling to add a Done(Check) button like [Google Calender(right one)](http://codemink.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Adding-calendar-events.jpg) on the top right of the dialog fragment.

Currently, I'm displaying a title and a map inside the Dialog Fragment. Is there a way to customise the dialog fragment like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style to [STYLE_NO_FRAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#STYLE_NO_FRAME) and create a custom dialog layout. Then you'd be free to add any views you want, including buttons in a title area.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to follow a pattern in Google Apps, thought there would be something straight forward. But this helps, Setting the style also made it look better, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom dialog fragment, this is an example how to do that:

```
public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    public static EditNameDialog newInstance(String title) {
        EditNameDialog frag = new EditNameDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Enter Name");
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }
}
```

you can change the **fragment_edit_name.xml** and put your buttons, title, map...

PS: i copy this code from [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment)